# Auto-complete HTML tags

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When editing a file in the Sources panel (I've set up a workspace and mapped files to system resources), is there a way to auto-complete an HTML tag? E.g. I type `<p>` and DevTools automatically creates the closing tag (`</p>`), or I press a keyboard shortcut to insert the closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this functionality does not exist in DevTools.

[Open feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360242) to allow developers to enable custom extensions which could then allow for this.